# Trying to send body parameters but req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, body-parser

I have one route that I use to return some data considering the body parameters.

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const ReportsController = require('./controllers/ReportIngredientController')
const routes = express.Router()

routes.get('/report', ReportsController.show)

module.exports = routes;
```

I created a postman call to test it and this is the body I am sending

```
[
    {
        "name": "acem"
    },
    {
        "name": "sal grosso"
    },
    {
        "name": "caldo de carne"
    }
]
```

but when I try to get the "req.body" at the controller, it is getting empty.
Can anyone help with this kind of error?

Comment: HTTP GET does not have (or expect) body. Try with POST or PUT instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to the problem I had mentioned, in this case, I needed to use params from the Get method.

```
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: "http://192.168.0.2:3333/report",
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: {},
    params: {
      name: ["'acem'", "'sal grosso'"]
    }
  })
    .then(function (res) {
      // handle success
      console.log("######## CARD CALL - IT's OK!!! :: ", res.data);
      setRecipeList(res)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('API CALL - /report - error: ',error);
    })
```

that is what I used to get the result I needed and send the query params to the API.

thanks a lot for the answers.